# Trying to diagnose a Google Maps/Safari Issue

Tags: google-maps, safari

Our site is able to be accessed through FF/IE/Chrome, etc. however when a user opens the site in Safari, it doesn't load the google maps box. It stays the grey loading color.

We use Google Maps v3 and geolocation to set the default position of the map, and if they deny location or something, we have a fallback to an IP service to center it somewhat close to them. Works everywhere but on Safari (multiple versions). It just hangs.

Any ideas at how I can diagnose this? I'm running Windows 7/XP so it's tough to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [firebug lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) version

and also have a try with the built-in developer tools.
This thread [Debugging javascript in Safari for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388646/debugging-javascript-in-safari-for-windows/388658#388658) says more about this.

Comment: I'll give this a shot. So there's no dev tools in Safari at all that are native?

Comment: @slandau, the second link point to an answer that shows how to enable the built-in dev tools.

Comment: Thanks man. Got the error. I'll make another post to see if anyone has gotten this before.